# Trying to define function - method definition not found

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to define a method/function and specifying this

In my .h : [image]

In my .m : [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function/method name should be same in both files .h and .m

```
- (int) getBestScore:(int)score1 andNum2:(int)score2
{
   //Write your code here
}
```

Comment: after I did this, I now get the error "implicit declaration of function is invalid in c99

Comment: any ideas why this change would caus this?

Comment: Where you declared the function?

Answer (score 0):

its because function signatures, names are different. Try using same as in .h file.

Unless compiler unable to find exact function as defined in .h file, it will throw this warning.

You can clearly see both are different.